# How to create and maintain a Data Extension of Marketing Cloud Admins?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have ~200 admins across ~40 business units, and I would like to maintain a data extension with their names, emails, permission levels, and last login date.  Is this possible to do programatically with only Marketing Cloud tools?  (SSJS, Ampscript, Cloudpages, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks possible using [AMPscript and the SOAP Web Service API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ampscriptSOAPAPI.htm).

- [SOAP Object: Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/account.htm)
- Example: [Manage Enterprise 2.0 Accounts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/managing_enterprise_20_accounts_with_the_web_services_api.htm)

You should be able to retrieve User Account information by creating a "RetrieveRequest" object (In AmpScript, on a Cloud Page) and saving the results in a Data Extension.
Depending on your code language background, this could also be achieved in SSJS allowing you to put it in an Automation Studio activity.
I hope this answers the "How" it could be achieved.